# Decreasing the stepsize of Y Axis

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Is there a way to set the YSTEP of the graph?

We are trying to show a chart with the below data

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graph"),
            [
                 [1,10,10],
                 [2,20.11,20],
                 **[3,10.111,10]**,
                 [4,20,20]],
            {labels: [ "x", "A", "B" ]});
```

but the out put is rounded with 0.01, and we are getting as

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graph"),
            [
                 [1,10,10],
                 [2,20.11,20],
                 **[3,10.11,10]**,
                 [4,20,20]],
            {labels: [ "x", "A", "B" ]});
```

How to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the [`digitsAfterDecimal`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#digitsAfterDecimal) option to 3 (it defaults to 2):

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graph"),
            [
                 [1,10,10],
                 [2,20.11,20],
                 [3,10.111,10],
                 [4,20,20]],
            {
              labels: [ "x", "A", "B" ],
              digitsAfterDecimal: 3
            });
```